# Rails couldn't find file jquery purr

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using rails 3.2.3

I included the following files in my application.js

```
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
```

It now looks like this

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
//= require_tree
```

I'm getting an error saying:

couldn't find file 'jquery.purr'

Comment: Is the file in `app/assets/javascript`?

Comment: Is it an actual file I need in my folder? Where do I get the file?

Comment: Never heard of it. Probably from the project homepage? http://code.google.com/p/jquery-purr/

Comment: I got this working on a different project before and I don't remember having to save any files to my javascripts folder

Comment: It works, answer and Ill give you a tick :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails doesn't magically know where to download scripts from.

You have to download and put them in the `app/assets/javascript` directory.

jQuery Purr is found here: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-purr/

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the current HEAD of the best_in_place gem, you don't need to download jquery.purr. It's included in the gem as best_in_place.purr. So you would add the following to your application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require best_in_place
//= require best_in_place.purr
```

Note that this does not give decent CSS for the purr notification. For that you can do something similar to what the best_in_place [test app](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/blob/master/test_app/app/assets/stylesheets/style.css.erb) does (lines 62 through 87 at the time of posting).